# Python:subprocess:Reading a string from the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I would like to read each line from a terminal program and have the python program react to it.
The program starts fine but I am having trouble making it read lines from the terminal.
Help on doing so would be appreciated.

```
import subprocess as sp
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text=Text(root)
proc = sp.Popen(["java", "-Xmx1536M", "-Xms1536M", "-jar", 
"b.jar"],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,)
while True:
    line=proc.poll()
    if(line=="Read Time Out"):
         proc.stdin.write('stop')
    if(line=="Unloading Dimension"):
         text.insert(INSERT,"Ready for command")
```

For example:
If the terminal displays: Hello
How would I be able to read the string "Hello" from the terminal.

Comment: `proc.stdout.readline()` will read a single line of STDOUT from the subprocess. These lines will contain your text, which you'll need to parse.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX: it is not that simple. The output may be block-buffered. See [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: Well when I do proc.stdout.readline() I can see all the output but I cant seem to be able to get the script to react to a line that is outputted. It wont read the line and then react to it. So then I said ok is it not reading the line or is the shutdown cmd is wrong so I changed it to just shutdown the computer and it still didnt work (if (line=="Read Time Out"): os.system("poweroff")